# Templated function accepting char*

Tags: c++, templates

I have a templated function and I did not know how to write the specilization for the type *unsigned const char** !?!

I did it for simple types (int, long ...) as below :

```
template <typename T>
void ConvertTypeToString(const T p_cszValue, std::string& p_szValue)
{
    p_szValue = p_cszValue;     
}

//Template Specialization for int
template <>
void ConvertTypeToString<int>(const int p_iValue, std::string& p_szValue)
{           
    GetFormattedString(p_iValue,p_szValue);
}

//Template Specialization for double
template <>
void ConvertTypeToString<double>(const double p_dValue, std::string& p_szValue)
{               
    GetFormattedString(p_dValue,p_szValue);     
}
```

And here Where I stuck, I couldn't fugure out what should I write? ther code below dosen't compile.

```
//for unsigned char* const   
template <>
void ConvertTypeToString<unsigned char*>(const unsigned char* p_ucValue, std::string& p_szValue)
{   
    p_szValue.push_back(p_ucValue);
}
```

So what is the correct code to write to take in consideration the **usigned char* const** ?

Than k you

Comment: whats wrong about your attempt?

Comment: You can only `push_back` single `char`s onto a `std::string`. What do you intend the function to do, seeing as `char` can be either signed or unsigned?

Comment: I want to push_back the string pointyed by char*

Comment: Someone was eloquently told me that a "leading const is misleading". And I'm still amazed how often they are proven right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You placed the `const` in a wrong place, it should be:

```
template <>
void ConvertTypeToString<unsigned char*>(unsigned char* const p_ucValue, std::string& p_szValue)
{   
    p_szValue.push_back(p_ucValue);
}
```

Comment: And what you really want is to accept `const unsigned char`, then `template <> void ConvertTypeToString<const unsigned char*>(const 
 unsigned char* const p_ucValue, ...`

Answer (score 1):

It is usually preferred to add an overload instead of a template specialization. This allows you to pass any parameters, including the pointer to const:

```
void ConvertTypeToString(const unsigned char* const p_ucValue, std::string& p_szValue) { p_szValue.push_back(p_ucValue); }
```